# What is the difference between a Broadcaster and a Beacon in BLE

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, bluetooth-gatt

What is the difference between broadcaster and beacons? From what I understand a broadcaster is a role in the GAP which sends out advertisements which contain data and are unable to make connections. They usually work in tandem with observers. Beacons do the same thing so what is the difference?

Answer (score 3):

It's a bit like asking what is the difference between a HTTP server and a Web Server. A Web Server is a computer that stores web sites which it makes available over the internet, while a HTTP server is a piece of software that implements the server part of the HTTP protocol.

A Broadcaster is a role in the GAP specification which simply sends out advertisements, just as you say. It's defined in section 2.2.2.1 of the GAP chapter (in the Core v5.3 specification). Observer is the opposite role.

The word "beacon" is not present anywhere in the >3000 pages long Bluetooth Core specification. It's a term made up by industry, presumably because it works good in marketing or is generally a good name to describe this type of product. Beacons typically send out their positions using BLE advertisements for location tracking purposes but can also be connectable for various purposes.

Broadcaster is just a technical term and Broadcasters do not have a specific product purpose, which beacons on the other hand usually have. For example, iBeacon is a product which uses a specific data format containing identifiers. This product then uses the Broadcaster role and sends this data over BLE.

Answer (score 2):

There is no difference. While `broadcaster` is a technical term used in the Bluetooth specification, `beacon` is simply the name of a class of products based on Bluetooth LE technology.